# How to add mp3 support with CFBundleTypeName

Tags: iphone, ios, associations

In applications like [PDF Reader Lite](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pdf-reader-lite/id368377690?mt=8), it's possible to associate PDF type with the app in such a way, when a PDF file will be opened in an app like Safari or Email, it will show an option to open the file in PDF Reader Lite app too.

Is it possible to implement similar thing for mp3? I have tried to add below tags in Info.plist file in below way.

```
<array>
     <dict>
          <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
          <string>MPG3</string>
          <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
          <string>Alternate</string>
          <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
          <array>
               <string>public.mp3</string>
          </array>
     </dict>
</array>
```

But when I open an mp3 URL (a URL having an extension .mp3 at end like this - http://sound18.mp3pk.com/indian/7khoonmaaf/7khoonmaaf01(www.songs.pk).mp3 it doesn't display the option to open the file in my app.

Will anyone please help me out for this?

Thanks,

Comment: Is the slash at the end on purpose?

Comment: It's by mistake. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It actually works if you set this dict to the *CFBundleDocumentTypes* key.

You can test if it works by sending a mail with a mp3 file to your iPhone or iPad. Hold down on the attachment and the *UIDocumentInteractionController*-View will pop up. Other applications can also use the *UIDocumentInteractionController* ([see SDK documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDocumentInteractionController_class/Reference/Reference.html)) to allow opening files with another app.

However, Mobile Safari doesn't do that for all media types. So it won't work when you open the URL directly.

An alternative would be to register an URL scheme for your app (*CFBundleURLTypes*), then you could pass the URL-String to the app through that custom URL scheme (*myapp://www.example.com/file.mp3*).

Comment: OK. I was more keen to do it with Mobile Safari. I will check for the other points of your answer. And thanks for your answer.